# Python, unittest.main() won't test my program

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to create a very basic unittest.TestCase class, just to check I know how to do it. However, when I try to run tests, it won't do them. I wrote a very basic piece of code that should in theory run 1 test, but it keeps saying that it ran none. Here is what I wrote:

```
import unittest
class c(unittest.TestCase):
    kv = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
    def cc(self):
        for k, v in self.kv:
            res = tothis(k)
            self.assertEqual(v, res)
```

The function `res` wasn't written, but that's OK as at this stage I don't care if the tests fail, I just want to see if I can run them.

After putting in the coding I should be able to run tests like this:

```
unittest.main()
```

It just keeps saying that it ran no tests, but it should run a test for `self.assertEqual`. Why isn't it running the test?

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format your code properly.  Why is your test class named `c`?  What causes you to think that will work?

Answer (score 6):

the name of your test function should start with "test".

```
import unittest
class c(unittest.TestCase): 
   kv = ((1, 2), (3, 4)) 
   def test_cc(self): 
      for k, v in self.kv: 
          res = tothis(k) 
          self.assertEqual(v, res)
```